# What is the difference between `ifelse` and the ternary operator in Julia?

Tags: julia

Suppose I have this code:

```
cond = true
a = cond ? 1 : 2
b = ifelse(cond, 1, 2)
```

What is the difference between the two operations?

Comment: Note that you can also write a normal `if` statement on one line. I often prefer that look. `if cond 1 else 2 end`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In the example you wrote, there is no effective difference.  If, however, the two branches were more complicated than simple integer literals, then there is a difference:

```
julia> f() = (println("calling f()!"); 1)
f (generic function with 1 method)

julia> g() = (println("calling g()!"); 2)
g (generic function with 1 method)

julia> cond ? f() : g()
calling f()!
1

julia> ifelse(cond, f(), g())
calling f()!
calling g()!
1
```

In other words, `ifelse` is just a normal function. And just like all other functions, its arguments are *always* evaluated.  The ternary operator is *syntax* equivalent to:

```
if cond
    f()
else
    g()
end
```

Note that in some cases, this can result in a difference in the instructions your processor uses (that is, changing a branch to a lookup) which can have subtle performance implications beyond the costs of the code in the two branches (or not so subtle if inside a `@simd` loop)... but often Julia and LLVM are often smart enough to do the best thing either way if it's possible.

Answer (score 1):

Another general difference is that the `ifelse` function can be broadcasted

```
julia> ifelse.([true, true, false], [1, 1, 1], [0, 0, 0])
3-element Vector{Int64}:
 1
 1
 0
```

whereas the ternary operator cannot.