# Julia ternary operator without `else`

Tags: if-statement, syntax, conditional-statements, julia, conditional-operator

Consider the ternary operator in Julia

```
julia> x = 1 ; y = 2

julia> println(x < y ? "less than" : "not less than")
less than
```

**Question:** Is there a way to omit the `:` part of the statement ? Something which would be equivalent to

```
if condition
    # dosomething
end
```

without writing that if the condition is not met, nothing should be done.

*NB: I researched the answer but nothing came out, even in related questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39790031/does-julia-have-a-ternary-conditional-operator), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65741521/what-is-the-difference-between-ifelse-and-the-ternary-operator-in-julia))*

Comment: I don't know Julia, but if you don't want an else body, you don't want a ternary (in every language I know). The purpose of a ternary is to evaluate to one of two values based on a condition. If you want to run side effects, don't use a ternary (conditional expression).

Comment: Thanks @Carcigenicate, maybe I shouldn't use the ternary operator in that case indeed.

Comment: FWIW, "ternary" means "composed of 3 parts"... So the question sounds a bit like "Can I have a 3-part thing without the 3rd part?"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Just do:

```
condition && do_something
```

For an example:

```
2 < 3 && println("hello!")
```

Explanation:

`&&` is a short-circut operator in Julia. Hence, the second value will be only evaluated when it needs to be evaluated. Hence when the first `condition` evaluates to `false` there is no need to evaluate the second part.

Finally, note that you can also use this in an assignment:

```
julia> x = 2 > 3 && 7
false

julia> x = 2 < 3 && 7
7
```

This however makes `x` type unstable so you might want to wrap the right side of the assignment around `Int` such as `x = Int(2 > 3 && 7)` than your `x` will be always an `Int`.

Comment: Not a ternary operator (as ternary operators are inappropriate in that situation, as pointed out by @Carcigenicate) but this is what I was looking for, thanks !

Comment: I extended the answer to show that a ternary-like behavior is possible!

Comment: Ok. If ternary behaviour is wanted, using `x = Int(2 > 3 && 7)` seems like the best option. Great and quick answer, thanks !

Comment: There's also the companion operator `||` which evaluates the second expression only if the first expression is `false`.

Answer (score 8):

`&&` is commonly used for this because it is short, but you have to know the trick to read it. I sometimes find it more readable to just use a regular old if statement. In Julia, it need not be across multiple lines if you want to save space.

```
julia> x = 1; y = 2;

julia> if (x < y) println("less than") end
less than

julia> if (x > y) println("greater than") else println("not greater than") end
not greater than
```

Note that the parentheses are not required around the conditional in this case; I just add them for clarity. Also, note that I moved `println` next to the string for clarity, but you can place the whole `if` statement inside `println`, as you did in the question, if you prefer.